# My website showing 404 page not found again and and again . how to solve that?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, http-error

My website showing `404 page not found` again and and again . how to solve that?  After permalink changes , 
it's working well for sometimes then **again showing same error**.

**Steps I tried:**

1. permalink changes
2. .htaccess edit
3. clear caches
4. made  .htaccess  file as read only..

But I need permanent solution . Please help..

Answer (score 1):

First of all please make sure mod_Rewrite is enabled on your server and working.

Please check your error log files and post the errors in your question, it will help us to detect the issue.

Comment: How to enable mod_Rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

As you're writing that you've already made the .htaccess read-only, I assume that it doesn't change when the problem occurs?

It sounds like something is messing with the wordpress rewrites. Maybe you could add a filter to [rewrite_rules_array](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array), use [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/function.debug-backtrace.php) and log that to a file to track down the code that is changing the rewrites.

Comment: Can you please tell me detail procedure ??

Comment: IF it is something messing with the rewrites, you might be able to track it down by adding something like https://pastebin.com/yL1PLatF in your functions.php
However, you'll still have to manually go through that log and find the problem. It will save two files in your document root (if it's writable), rewrite-changes.json and rewrite-changes.log. rewrite-changes.log is the one you'll be interested in.